# Submitting a JCL via FTP

Tags: ftp, mainframe, jcl

I need to submit a JCL via FTP.
Wrote below code for it:

```
open server.com 
uname
password
quote site LRECL=80 BLKSIZE=27920 RECFM=FB
literal SITE FILETYPE=JES 
GET 'PDS.NAME(JCLNAME)' 'LOCAL\PATH\file.txt'
disconnect
bye
```

The problem is that even after the job gets completed in spool, it takes around 10 minutes before this script gets completed.
It seems to get stuck at **125 When Job is done, Will retrieve its output**.
Maybe i am missing some pre initialization. Please advise.

Comment: "125 When Job is done, Will retrieve its output" I do not see this in your posted code so what are you saying? That it takes 10 minutes for the JCL to reach the mainframe or 10 minutes for the JCL to reach the mainframe and execute or something else?

Comment: @NicC 125 is a reply from the FTP saying it will get the output when the job is completed. OP is saying that after the job has completed, it takes around 10 minutes to retrieve the job information.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the JES system doesn't really know how to process the request. If you take a read of the [Steps for submitting a job and automatically receiving output](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.halu001/autosubmit.htm) article it explains that in order to get the output of the job automatically, the JCL JOBNAME must be USERIDx. So if my userid is ABC123, then my JOBNAME should be ABC123A. They also recommend a slightly different set up than you. Try this:

```
open server.com 
USERID
password
SITE FILEtype=JES NOJESGETBYDSN 
GET 'PDS.NAME(USERIDx)' 'LOCAL\PATH\file.txt'
disconnect
bye
```

When I tried your FTP commands, I got the same results (waiting for 10 minutes). I think it has to do with the JES interface level and how long the different files are held for. Using the commands above (and using the proper naming), the SYSOUTS will comeback when the job has completed as long as they are in HELD status. If there are some outputs that are not in HELD status, it will skip them.

Answer (score 0):

Confused why you're using 'GET'.
I have always used 'PUT' to submit a JCL via FTP.

Here's a snippet of a batch job I'd use to submit JCL via FTP:

```
::: -- FTP Compress DOC --
:ftp_COMPRESS
echo.
echo  " ----------------------------------- "
echo  " COMPRESSING dataset                 " 
echo  " --------------------------------------- "
IF EXIST ftptemp.txt del ftptemp.txt
echo user %FTPUserID%>> ftptemp.txt
echo %FTPPwd%>> ftptemp.txt
echo cd ..>> ftptemp.txt
echo cd DATASET>> ftptemp.txt
echo del %filename%>> ftptemp.txt
echo quote site file=jes>> ftptemp.txt
echo put compit.jcl>> ftptemp.txt
echo quote site file=seq
echo quit>> ftptemp.txt
ftp -n -s:ftptemp.txt %host%

pause
```

Here's the JCL job on my local machine saved as compit.jcl, same directory as .bat:

```
 //COMPIT    JOB CARD                                          
 //*-------------------------------------------------------------
 //COMPRESS EXEC PGM=IEBCOPY
 //SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*
 //LIB DD DSN=DATASET,DISP=OLD
 //SYSIN DD *
  COPY INDD=LIB,OUTDD=LIB
 /*
```

The job itself was a quick way I'd compress a dataset before uploading more members to it.